# @html.BeginForm using jquery Ajax doesn't work totally

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have to use Ajax with asp.net mvc on a formular. My manager doesn't want that I use @Ajax.BeginForm and so I have to use ajax with Jquery method.
My problem is even my code seems work, when it goes in the controller, the controller return a new page ( like the form was submit with a simple POST) and so I haven't the ajax advantages. I really don't know where I did a mistake or if I did't wrong. Here my code:

HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCtrl", null, FormMethod.Post,new { id = "addGroupForm" }) )
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identitye</i>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.group.Name, htmlAttributes: new { id = "Description" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.group.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "validate" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.group.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
    </div>

    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.idList, new MultiSelectList(Model.permissionList, "Id" , "Name"), null)


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
        $('#addGroupForm').submit(function () {
            alert(this.methode);
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                //the action is send with this ajax request and the send works
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("yo");
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddCtrl(GroupViewModels grp)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("YOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(grp.group.Name);
            return Json("{yo:toto}");
        }
```

Comment: Check for script errors. If there are any errors before `return false` it will not prevent the redirection. `event.preventDefault()` is better in this regard since you'd place it at the top of the submit handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false` when using ajax on form submission

**Try this:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#addGroupForm').submit(function (e) {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            //the action is send with this ajax request and the send works
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("yo");
                }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```